# Calling Additional Scripts from Arduino-Cli when uploading to a board

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to an Arduino Mini that it normally communicates with over I2C. But I'd also like to be able to reflash the Mini with new code using Arduino-Cli from the Raspberry Pi (kinda rhymes!).  This would involve connecting the Raspberry Pi's GPIO serial port to the Arduino's serial port.  Additionally, the Arduino Mini requires a manual reset to be applied before its code can be reflashed, which is something the Raspberry Pi can do by toggling a GPIO pin attached to the Mini's reset line.  I can do this with a simple Python script.  The question is:  is there a way for Arduino-Cli to call additional scripts as part of the upload command?